# DynamoDB connector in degraded state

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-dynamodb, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to write Kafka topic data to local Dynamodb. However, the Connector state is always in **degraded** state. Below is my connector cofig properties.

```
{
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "name": "dynamo-sink-connector",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.aws.dynamodb.DynamoDbSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "topics": [
    "KAFKA_STOCK"
  ],
  "aws.dynamodb.pk.hash": "value.companySymbol",
  "aws.dynamodb.pk.sort": "value.txTime",
  "aws.dynamodb.endpoint": "http://localhost:8000",
  "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": [
    "broker:29092"
  ]
}
```

I was referring to this https://github.com/RWaltersMA/mongo-source-sink and replaced mongo with DynamoDB sink

Could someone provide a simple working example, please?

Comment: Please show the connector logs... What do you mean "replaced Mongo with dynamo? Those databases aren't the same and that repo appear to only be for Mongo. Plus, how would you be running dynamo on localhost?

Comment: Are you using Docker? Can you share the compose file? If you are using Docker, Dynamo is not `localhost`, it would be the Connect container itself

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, Thanks! for checking. I now moved dynamoDB inside the docker and sink connector is working for String Key and Value converters. However, when I tried the KafakAvroSerializer for value, it is complaining about shcema.registry.url missing though I provided the schema.registry.url .

Comment: You need `value.converter.schema.registry.url`, for example, not the url key by itself, but feel free to edit your question to include the latest configs and errors.

Comment: I configured below properties in my connect:      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"

Comment: String converters don't use the registry. Seems fine to me, but you would ideally put those properties in the connector itself, not as container env vars

Comment: Many Thanks! It is working fine :) now when I added it to connector config. Now my connector config looks like below. Really appreciate your prompt response

Comment: ```{
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
  "name": "dynamo-sink",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.aws.dynamodb.DynamoDbSinkConnector",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "topics": [
    "stockdata"
  ],
  "aws.dynamodb.pk.hash": "value.stockCode",
  "aws.dynamodb.endpoint": "http://dynamodb-local:8000",
  "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": [
    "broker:19092"
  ]
}```

Comment: Feel free to provide your full working config as an answer below rather than just a comment

Answer (score 1):

Below is the full example for using AWS DynamoDB Sink connector.

Thanks! to @OneCricketeer for his suggestions

Dockerfile-DynamoDBConnect which is referred to in docker-compose.yml below

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest

ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-aws-dynamodb:latest
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "19092:19092"
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:19092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: localhost
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'

  dynamodb-local:
    command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"
    image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - localnet
    volumes:
      - "./docker/dynamodb:/home/dynamodblocal/data"
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-DynamoDBConnect
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:19092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      # Assumes image is based on confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:latest which is pulling 5.3.0 Connect image
      CLASSPATH: "/usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-5.3.0.jar"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
    command: "bash -c 'if [ ! -d /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-datagen ]; then echo \"WARNING: Did not find directory for kafka-connect-datagen (did you remember to run: docker-compose up -d --build ?)\"; fi ; /etc/confluent/docker/run'"
    volumes:
      - ../build/confluent/kafka-connect-aws-dynamodb:/usr/sahre/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-aws-dynamodb
      - $HOME/.aws/credentialstest:/home/appuser/.aws/credentials
      - $HOME/.aws/configtest:/home/appuser/.aws/config

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.3.0
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:19092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'


  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.0.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    networks:
      - localnet
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:19092
      CONTROL_CENTER_KAFKA_CodeCamp_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:19092

      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_METRICS_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1

      # Amount of heap to use for internal caches. Increase for better throughput
      CONTROL_CENTER_STREAMS_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 100000000
      CONTROL_CENTER_STREAMS_CONSUMER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS: "960032"
      CONTROL_CENTER_STREAMS_NUM_STREAM_THREADS: 1

      # HTTP and HTTPS to Control Center UI
      CONTROL_CENTER_REST_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:9021
      PORT: 9021

      # Connect
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT1_CLUSTER: http://connect:8083
      # Schema Registry
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081

networks:
  localnet:
    attachable: true
```

Java Example to publish Messages in Avro Format

```
public class AvroProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Variables (bootstrap server, topic name, logger)
        final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
        final String bootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092";
        final String topicName = "stockdata";

        // Properties declaration (bootstrap server, key serializer, value serializer
        // Note use of the ProducerConfig object
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");

        // Create Producer object
        // Note the generics
        KafkaProducer<String, Stock> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);

        Stock stock = Stock.newBuilder()
                .setStockCode("APPL")
                .setStockName("Apple")
                .setStockPrice(150.0)
                .build();

        // Create ProducerRecord object
        ProducerRecord<String, Stock> rec = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, stock);

        // Send data to the producer (optional callback)
        producer.send(rec);

        // Call producer flush() and/or close()
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
    }
}
```